# self.tabBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new]; is not worked after iOS 10

Tags: ios, uitabbar

Before iOS 10, we can hide shadow gradient line by using

```
self.tabBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
```

But this solution does not work after iOS 10, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found a universal solution ignore iOS version

**Objective-C**

```
BOOL isFound = NO;
for (UIView *view in self.tabBar.subviews) {
    for (UIView *v in view.subviews) {
        if (v.frame.size.height < 2.0f) {
            v.hidden = YES;
            isFound = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isFound) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this its may be helpful.

**--> For Objective C**

```
1. [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]]; 
2. [[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
3. [[UITabBar appearance] setValue:@(YES) forKeyPath:@"_hidesShadow"];
4. [[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage: nil];
```

**--> For Swift**

```
1. UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
2. UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()
3. UITabBar.setValue(true, forKey: "_hidesShadow")
4. UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = nil
```